Select en laravel no recupera entrada antigua al presionar el boton editar
Estoy en un crud de laravel y no me trae las entradas antiguas en el formulario de update en los campos 'subcategorías' y 'estante' que son claves foráneas y en 'suppliers' que es relacion m_m (los demás campos que no son clave foránea si trae las entradas antiguas). Uso el método old() y nada aún (el crud va bien en actualizar, eliminar y crear) cabe destacar que este formulario esta en una ventana modal, tanto de crear como de actualizar.
controlador
 public function index()
    {
        $productos = Producto::with('subcategoria', 'estante', 'suppliers')
        ->select('productos.id', 'subcategorias.nombreSubcategoria', 'productos.nombreProducto', 'productos.precioUnitario', 'productos.stockMinimo', 'productos.stockMaximo', 'productos.cantidad', 'estantes.nombreEstante', 'suppliers.supplier_name')
        ->join('subcategorias', 'productos.subcategoria_id', '=', 'subcategorias.id')
        ->join('estantes', 'productos.estante_id', '=', 'estantes.id')
        ->join('productos_x_suppliers', 'productos.id', '=', 'productos_x_suppliers.producto_id')
        ->join('suppliers', 'productos_x_suppliers.supplier_id', '=', 'suppliers.id')
        ->get();


        $subcategorias = DB::table('subcategorias')->select('id', 'nombreSubcategoria')->get();
        $estantes = DB::table('estantes')->select('nombreEstante', 'id')->get();


        $suppliers = DB::table('suppliers')->select('id', 'supplier_name')->get();



    
        return view('productos.index', compact('productos', 'subcategorias', 'estantes', 'suppliers'));
    }

el formulario de update:
<form action="{{route('productos.update',$p->id)}}" method="POST">
      @csrf    
      @method('PUT')   
      <div
        class="row justify-content-center align-items-center g-2"
        >
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <label for="subcategoria_id" class="form-label">Subcategorias</label>
          <select name="subcategoria_id" id="subcategoria_id" class="form-control" required>
            @foreach ($subcategorias as $subcategoria)
                <option value="{{ $subcategoria->id }}" {{ old('subcategoria_id', $p->subcategoria_id) == $subcategoria->id ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                    {{ $subcategoria->nombreSubcategoria }}
                </option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
        
        </div>

    
     <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center g-2">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <label for="estante" class="form-label">Estante</label>
        <select name="estante_id" id="estante" class="form-control"  required>
          <option disabled>Selecciona una</option>
          @foreach ($estantes as $e)
          <option value="{{old($su->id}}">{{$e->nombreEstante}}</option>
          @endforeach
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <label for="supplier" class="form-label">Proveedor</label>
         <select name="supplier_id[]" id="supplier" class="form-control"  required>
          <option disabled>Selecciona una</option>
          @foreach ($suppliers as $su)
          <option value="{{old($su->id)}}">{{$su->supplier_name}}</option>
          @endforeach
        </select> 
      </div>
     </div>


yo veo que tienes {{old($su->id}} antes del nombre del estante, te falta cerrar un paréntesis
